# c++ , error: 'shared_ptr' in namespace 'std' does not name a template type

Tags: c++, boost, g++, rhapsody

I tried to define a smart pointer to my structure with rhapsody and I have already  included the header file "memory". But I ve got the error above

```
 typedef std::shared_ptr<my_structure> %s;
```

Comment: What is that `%` doing? Pretty sure no compiler accepts that.

Comment: You should include a full example program and the error in in future questions.

Comment: I meant shared_ptr and it didn't work niether

Comment: %s won't fix it either. You can not use `%` for this at all. It would help if you posted more code so that we could understand what you are trying to do instead of how you want to do it.

Comment: I know but shared_ptr is before the %s, btw %s is the name of the variable

Comment: Edit your question and put the type name in there instead of %s (which is wrong).

Comment: I mean `typedef std::shared_ptr<my_structure> mytype;` Then we would not have had the confusion about %1  or %s which are both wrong and can't possibly work.

Comment: I know this is a dumb question, but have you included `<memory>` ?

Comment: yes I did, I have  included it in SpecIncludes in rhapsody

Answer (score 8):

I think you mean `std::shared_ptr` and not `std::shared`.

Also `%` is not legal in a type name in C++.

---

If your intent is to create a type alias, then you should do something like this

```
using MyType_t = std::shared_ptr<my_structure>;
```

If your intent is to create a variable of type `std::shared_ptr<my_structure>`, then you should do this

```
std::shared_ptr<my_structure> ptr;
```

Comment: you are right, I meant  std::shared_ptr

Comment: @sahbi.m take a look at the edited answer

Comment: `typedef std::shared_ptr<my_structure> MyType_t` is equivalent to `using MyType_t = std::shared_ptr<my_structure>`

Answer (score -2):

no %  needed
access specifier comes up with % usually in printf("%s",arg);

best way is 
std::shared_ptr ptr;

Comment: "%s" is a **format** specifier, not an access specifier. But it's not valid as the name of a type or of a variable. Regardless, this does not answer the question.